# UI not being properly updated on LG device (works on others!)

Tags: android, lg

I'm writing an app that I've been testing on my Nexus 5 with Android 5 and in the emulator on different DPI and API levels. While some UI magic is missing on pre-L Android, everything worked just fine and I know how to work around these missing parts (e. g. implement touch feedback etc.)

I've implemented RecyclerView and CardView from the support library which worked just fine on my device and the emulators. There is data being fetched from the web so the "list" is being filled upon launch.

Now, I've tested the app on a LG G2 mini running Android 4.4.2. The UI is not being updated. The items are added, but I have to leave the Activity and come back again before I can see them.

This sounds like I've been missing runOnUiThread, but I didn't! Furthermore, why is this working on stock Android but not on an OEMs mod?